# Error converting field `additional_data` in table `catalog_eav_attribute` where `attribute_id`=114

Tags: magento2.2, magento-upgrade

After upgrading Magento 2.1.9 to 2.2.4. 
and Run command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`  getting this error.

**" Error converting field `additional_data` in table `catalog_eav_attribute` where `attribute_id`=114 using Magento\Framework\DB\DataConverter\SerializedToJson.
Fix data or replace with a valid value. "**

Any Suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: need to open the table in the DB and find the additional_data and make the empty places NULL.